# installing WSQ php library

Tags: php, ubuntu, shared-libraries, fingerprint

I followed these instructions to install the WSQ library for PHP 7 from (http://www.cognaxon.com/index.php?page=wsqlib_phpnotes#3) on ubuntu 18.04

Below is the error, which shows that the libraries are not loaded.

```
http://192.168.27.4/temp/
[Tue Feb 11 08:40:59.497934 2020] [php7:error] [pid 1173] [client 192.168.27.3:45372] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wsq_convert_image() in /var/www/html/temp/wsq_convert_image.php:3\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/temp/wsq_convert_image.php on line 3, referer: http://192.168.27.4/temp/
```

Additional information

```
a@a:~$ apache2 -v 
Server version: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2019-09-16T12:58:48
a@a:~$ 
a@a:~$ php -v
PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 (cli) (built: Jan 13 2020 18:39:59) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.2, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
a@a:~$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to info@cognaxon.com

I modified the php.ini file and added the extension line.

```
a@a:/var/www/html/temp$ cat  /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini | grep wsq
extension=wsq.so
```